# Trying to start function from a shared instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selector

I have instance of interface that displays a map.
I am calling to that map from other interface and displaying it, now i want to start a function (func5) that in the map interface.

I'm creating:

```
myMap *map = (myMap*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[map func5:2];
```

this `func5` i declared in myMap interface.

```
-(void) func5:(int) num;
```

but i'm getting an error when trying to run this line: [map func5:2];

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate func5:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x952b140'
```

what is the problem?

Comment: You will need to post more code to answer this question properly.  Show the declaration of the AppDelegate.

Comment: AppDelegate its a big file of all my app, what exactlly can be common to this problem there?

Comment: The existence of the `func5:` method for starters...  Also why the error message is `func5:` and yet you called `func5`.  Something is fishy...

Comment: Looks like you think the class you are calling is `myMap` but you are getting back an instance of `AppDelegate`.

Comment: yeah...that's the thing i dont understnat

Comment: I would imagine that `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` **would** return an `AppDelegate` object, so why do *you* think it would be a `myApp` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, its a terrible thing to put methods like this on the app delegate, generally you want those methods in their own instances.

Second, AppDelegate must have

```
- (void)func5;
```

declared in the header (that is AppDelegate.h)

From the code here I am assuming that by "instance" you mean your AppDelegate, and not something else like *MyMapClass *myMap;* thing.

If it is the second one then you have to make myMap a declared property in the header of the app delegate and then call it this way:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[deletage.myMap func5];
```

and add the header in where you want to call the function.

```
#include AppDelegate.h
```

STILL this is a terrible practice.

Comment: by "instance" i mean the myMap class, cant see why i getting the AppDelegate error here, i never used it in this part of code.

Comment: Try the second solution i posted. The error you get is because you are trying to make your app delegate perform a method which is declared on myMap Instance which is probably declared in the app delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the declaration of the function **func5**?

Check this properly, and provide the necessary arguments if necessary

```
[map func5];  // is how you have called your method
[AppDelegate func5:] // is what your eror has showed with ":" after the function name
```

They are two different things, depends on how you defined your method

Comment: I dont understand why i'm getting this error from `AppDelage`, I call to func5 that declared in myMap class. cant see why the `appDelegate` is involved here  @Luis Oscar